# Is there a way of extract output of bash script in Azure Pipeline

Tags: bash, azure, azure-pipelines

I have plenty of bash scripts with various variables that being piped into various scripts.

I've been wondering if I can extract an output of bash script that is activated by Azure Pipeline to be a pipeline variable for the rest of the Pipeline runtime?

Example:
`foo=$(date + %Y%m%d_%H%M%S)` output: 20200219_143400, I'd like to get the output for later use on the pipeline.

Comment: the variable `"$foo"` now has the value/output of  the `date` command. what is it that you want?

Comment: Did you tried `##vso[task.setvariable]` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#set-variables-in-scripts ?

Comment: @IvanIgnatiev I've done that but didn't fully understood it, because my variable is declared inside the bash task, and I need it for later use in the pipeline.

Comment: @Jetchisel I'd like to ```$foo``` variable output and use it on another bash tasks, as output variable but I can't find out how

Comment: @DorShamay in your example you need to launch somewhere in your Job1 in OutputsStep: `echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=foo;isOutput=true]$foo"` and to use it in another task you need to pass it to parameter of your script of Job2: `./myscript.sh $[ dependencies.Job1.outputs['OutputsStep.foo'] ]`

Comment: @IvanIgnatiev Can you please convert your comment to answer, I'll try this approach and update.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Depends on how you design your pipeline you can use [Azure Pipeline variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#set-variables-in-scripts):

1. Inside the same Job:

```
- job: Job1
  steps:
  - bash: |
      $WORKDIR/foo.sh
      echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=foo]$foo"
    name: FooStep
  - bash: |
      $WORKDIR/nextscript.sh $(FooStep.foo)
    name: NextScript

# ...
```

2. Different jobs:

```
- job: Job1
  steps:
  - bash: |
      $WORKDIR/foo.sh
      echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=foo;isOutput=true]$foo"
    name: FooStep
- job: Job2
  dependsOn: Job1
  steps:
  - bash: |
      $WORKDIR/job2script.sh $[ dependencies.Job1.outputs['FooStep.foo'] ]
    name: Job2ScriptStep

# ...
```

So, you need to "print to pipeline console" with `##vso[task.setvariable]` all variables you need to save to output, and after to pass them as scripts arguments values.

Comment: Thank you for your answer i'll check this approach and update

Comment: What would the whole contents of `foo.sh` need to look like to get this to work? I keep getting empty strings.

Comment: @robertwbradford for this question inside `foo.sh` we are waiting for something like in example above : `foo=$(date + %Y%m%d_%H%M%S)`

Comment: Sadly, for me, using the above approach in a bash will result in some parsing error:

`stageDependencies.ShouldPublishBook.outputs['ShouldPublishBook_Check.findTitle.result']

syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".ShouldPublishBook.outputs['ShouldPublishBook_Check.findTitle.result'] ")`